# Create an ADO.NET read only SQL Server data set using a stored procedure in VS2015/C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2015

I want to create an ADO.NET read only SQL Server data set using a stored procedure in VS2015 with C#. Is there a way to do this?

The problem is when I try to create the command object to set the stored procedure I want to use, it throws errors. I know I am missing something but I am unable to find anything in MS help files that give an example of how to do this. I do not want to use Linq! Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

```
try
{
     string connString = AdoHelper.ConnectionString;

     var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
     CommandType myCommand = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     using (myConnection)
     {
          myConnection.Open();
          // myCommand. = myConnection;
          // myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          // myCommand.CommandTimeout = 540;

          if (this.optInStockOnly.Checked == true)
          {
              myCommand.CommandText = "InventoryGetLookupDataInStockOnly"; // Stored procedure Name
          }
          else
          {
              myCommand.CommandText = "InventoryGetLookupData";     // Stored procedure name 
          }

          myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName: "@CurrentWareHouseCode", value: MyGlobals.CurrentUsersInfo.CurrentUserWarehousecode);

          SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

          if (reader.Read())
          {
              // set recordset here and do rest of the stuff I want
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: what "errors" it returns?

Comment: I just don't understand the thought process here? why take the time to post the question and not post the error? So many posters do this. why?

Comment: I see you got a downvote... at least two people complained that you didn't include the error so that is nice. Most times people downvote and don't tell you why. To avoid those in the future. Please take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and reword this before you get a bunch of vote downs for a bad question. Too many bad questions and you won't be allowed to ask questions again for a while.  Make it easy for us to help and make the question useful for people later. (Error messages are particularly important for the last) :)

Comment: Seems like you've not wired your command with the connection. check out this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you did not link the command to the connection object.

check out this example:

```
private static void CreateCommand(string queryString,
    string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandTimeout = 15;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text; // CommandType.StoredProcedure; in case this was a Proc
        command.CommandText = queryString; // Proc name

        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                reader[0], reader[1]));
        }
    }
}
```

More on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Mozart I do not want to use the Data reader, I want to create a recordset object e.g. Adodb.recordset rs  =  MyCommand. I appreciate you response and apologizing for not making my example clearer.

Comment: Mozart, I was able, with the help of your example, to achieve the solution I was looking for. I am unable to thank you enough for you help.

Comment: @EdA Well the example was was pretty much based on the sample code you've shown. Glad it helped